# Lists of member pointer functions

Tags: c++, stl, pointer-to-member

Say I have a class:

```
class A
{
public:
  void doSomething();
}
```

Where doSomething does something that explicitly relies on the internal state of the instance of A.

Now, I have a situation where I have a bunch of things of type A laying around, but I only want to call doSomething from a strict subset of them, so I want to stick them on the list.  In particular, what I really want to do is stick pointers to individual doSomethings() in the list.

**Can I do it?**  Do I declare it like:

```
std::list<(A::*)()> aDoSomethings;
```

I read [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146275/function-pointer-to-template-class-member-functions), it makes sense and I will go that route if I need to.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking at all.  Or rather, I think I understand, I just don't know why you think pointers to member functions have anything to do with it?  From what you're describing, your list would end up with a bunch of identical values.  You need to store a reference to your actual A objects in some way, or your list will be worthless.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it seems like you want to have a list of function pointers rather than pointers to specific object instances.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Can you do it?  Yes.  But its worthless given the situation you've described.  All instances of `A::doSomething` have the same address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're confused about how member function pointers work.  For a given class, there is only a single instance of any given function.  They are differentiated by the use of the implicit parameter `this`.  Basically, you can pretend you have the following mapping.

```
struct Struct { void Function(); }
Struct a;
a.Function();
```

turns into

```
struct Struct { }
void Function(Struct* this);
Struct a;
Function(&a);
```

So if you have a bunch of `Struct` objects, and you want to call `Function` on a small set of them, you don't store `Function`, you store `Struct`.

Pointers to member functions are used when you have *multiple* functions, that you want to call selectively.  So if you have two functions in your class, both of which take no paramters and return void, `void (Struct::*)()` can point to either of them.  But it still points to a specific function, of which there's only one.  You still need to provide the `this` parameter.

```
struct Struct {
  Struct(int v) : value(v) { }
  void One() { cout << "one: " << value << endl; }
  void Two() { cout << "two: " << value << endl; }
  int value;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Struct> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);

  std::vector<void (Struct::*)()> f;
  f.push_back(&Struct::One);
  f.push_back(&Struct::Two);
  f.push_back(&Struct::One);

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    (v[i].*f[i])();
}
```

Not the best example, but it gets the point across.  You can mix and match objects, with member functions.

*edit: An example without containers getting in the way

```
Struct a(5), b(10);
void (Struct::*one)() = &Struct::One;
void (Struct::*two)() = &Struct::Two;

(a.*one)();
(b.*one)();
(a.*two)();
(b.*two)();
```

Note the extra parenthesis.  `a.*one()` is insufficient.

Comment: That was an excellent explanation.  I'm grateful for it. I gather that likewise, I could call v[1].*f[2]() and I would get 'two: 1'.

Comment: @David, I chose really bad names.  `(v[0].*f[1])()` would give the result you expect, but I suspect you just got got confused by my hasty naming scheme.  `v[1]` has the value 2, and `f[2]` points to the function `One`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the simple OO approach:

```
struct Can_Do_Something
{
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class A : public Can_Do_Something
{
    ...
};

std::list<Can_Do_Something*> my_list;

my_list[n]->doSomething();
```

This is restrictively maintaining access to the part of A's interface - inherited through the Can_Do_Something type - that you plan to access via the list.  It documents and enforces that restriction.

If you have a preference for something closer to your original vision, consider...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

struct A
{
    A(int n) : n_(n) { }

    int f(int x) { std::cout << "A::f() this " << (void*)this
                           << ", n_ " << n_
                           << ", x_ " << x << '\n'; }

    int n_;
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::function<int (int n)> Function;
    typedef std::vector<Function> Functions;

    Functions functions;
    A a1(1), a2(2), a3(3);

    functions.push_back(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&A::f), &a1));
    functions.push_back(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&A::f), &a2));
    functions.push_back(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&A::f), &a3));

    for (Functions::iterator i = functions.begin();
            i != functions.end();
            ++i)
        (*i)(42);
}
```

Here, boost::function is used to create a callback to the specific functions you're interested in.

Comment: That idea is contained in the entry I mentioned in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

A member function pointer doesn't have a pointer to a particular instance: It describes how to call a member function with a certain signature given a `this` pointer and parameters.

Instead, put pointers to the objects you care about into the list, and then iterate over that list, calling `doSomething` on each item.

Comment: I assumed that 'this' was implicit in the function signature.  There are many questions on SO that ask about arrays of pointers-to-member-functions.  I'm curious what distinguishes them from STL containers.

Comment: The parameter `this` is implicit in the signature.  The *value* of the parameter is not.  How could it be?  What distinguishes an array of pointers to member functions from a standard library container?  The same thing that distinguishes an array of integers from a standard library container.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out boost::function and boost::bind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably want something like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
  string m_name;

  public:
    A(const string& name) : m_name(name) {} 
    void doSomething() { cout << m_name << "::doSomething()" << endl; }
};

int main(void) {
  A f1("f1");
  A f2("f2");
  A f3("f3");
  A f4("f4");
  vector<A*> foo_list;
  foo_list.push_back(&f1);
  foo_list.push_back(&f3);

  for (vector<A*>::iterator it = foo_list.begin(); it != foo_list.end(); *it++) {
    static_cast<A*>(*it)->doSomething();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to have a list of pointers to functions member that have to be doSomething()?

Then you can have a list of function pointers to a member of your class, but you'll need to provide the associated object with it, so why not simply keep a list of (pointers to) the objects?