# Member function pointer of template class

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

Assuming I have a class `myClass` defined as follows:

```
template<typename Type> class myClass {

    public:

        Type* pParent;
        void (Type::*func_exe) ();

        void execute();

};
```

And I want to use it as parameter for a function `fGiveMeYourClass`, which uses it to call it's member-function `execute`

```
void fGiveMeYourClass ( ?myClass? ){

    ..?.. ->execute();

}
```

since I don't care about what `Type` actually is in this template and only want this classes' member-function-pointer, I'd be fine with something like a typedef to accept that member-function-pointer as parameter of `fGiveMeYourClass`

I tried that already but my attepts seemed to fail:

```
template <typename Type> typedef void(myClass<Type>::*pMyClassExec)();
void fGiveMeYourClass(pMyClassExec pointerToMemberFunction);
```

Is there any other way this could be achieved or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not just `template <typename T> void fGiveMeYourClass(myClass<T> const & x){ x.execute(); }`? It's not clear where the function pointer is supposed to come in.

Comment: Well I know I could just template the whole function but since this class is used as a parameter of lots of other functions that would mean turning them all into templates and that doesn't look like the cleanest solution to me. I thought there might be an easier way... especially because I only care about the one member function of that class which works the same no matter what `Type` is.

Comment: You could declare `execute` as a virtual function in a non-templated base class, and pass around a pointer/reference to the base.

Comment: that actually worked :) thank you so much! I already found that kind of approach over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146275/function-pointer-to-template-class-member-functions) but I was unsure about how or if it would work for me...
I guess I'll have to take a look at [that](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) part of C++ again... the one I skipped because I thought learning it wouldn't help me for now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Alan Stokes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212870/alan-stokes) for this comment he posted on my question:

> You could declare execute as a virtual function in a non-templated base class, and pass around a pointer/reference to the base

This solved my problem.

In case it's interesting to someone:
I needed this to implement a class that could be passed on to a part of my game-engine to let the engine autonomously execute a custom piece of code ( a test-function? ) at a given event, e.g. when the user presses the "Debug-test-function"-button in-game. It however does have lots of other applications as well

Here is the code I use so far for these packaged commands:

```
class VE_COMMAND_PABA;
class VE_STANDARD_COMMAND;
template <typename ReturnValueType, typename Param1Type, typename Param2Type> class VE_FUNC_COMMAND;
template <typename ParentClassType, typename ReturnValueType, typename Param1Type, typename Param2Type> class VE_DERIVED_FUNC_COMMAND;

class VE_COMMAND_PABA {

    public:

        enum VE_COMMAND_TYPE {

            VE_CT_STANDARD,
            VE_CT_FUNC,
            VE_CT_DERIVED

        } paba_type;

        virtual void execute() = 0;
        virtual void Release() = 0;

};

class VE_STANDARD_COMMAND : public VE_COMMAND_PABA {

    private:


    public:

        enum VE_STANDARD_COMMAND_TYPE {

            VE_SCT_BOOL_TOGGLE,
            VE_SCT_INCREMENT,
            VE_SCT_DECREMENT,
            VE_SCT_SET_INT,
            VE_SCT_SET_FLOAT,
            VE_SCT_SET_BOOL

        } type;

        bool* pBOOL;
        int* pINT;
        float* pFLOAT;

        bool params_allocated;

        int* set_int;
        float* set_float;
        bool* set_bool;

        VE_COMMAND_PABA* command_exe; // <- REFERENCE TO BASE CLASS

        void execute();

        void Release(){

            if(this->command_exe != nullptr) this->command_exe->Release();

            if(this->type == VE_SCT_SET_BOOL && this->params_allocated) delete this->set_bool;
            if(this->type == VE_SCT_SET_FLOAT && this->params_allocated) delete this->set_float;
            if(this->type == VE_SCT_SET_INT && this->params_allocated) delete this->set_int;

            delete this; // bye bye ...

        };

};

template <typename ReturnValueType, typename Param1Type, typename Param2Type> class VE_FUNC_COMMAND : public VE_COMMAND_PABA {

    public:

        enum VE_FUNC_COMMAND_TYPE {

            VE_FCT_FUNC,
            VE_FCT_FUNC_PARAM,
            VE_FCT_FUNC_TWO_PARAM,

        } type;

        Param1Type* pParam1;
        Param2Type* pParam2;

        Param1Type** lpParam1;
        Param2Type** lpParam2;

        bool params_allocated;

        ReturnValueType (*func_exe) ();
        ReturnValueType (*func_param_exe) (Param1Type parameter);
        ReturnValueType (*func_two_param_exe) (Param1Type parameter1, Param2Type parameter2);

        void Release(){

            if(params_allocated){

                if(pParam1 != nullptr) free(pParam1);
                if(pParam2 != nullptr) free(pParam2);

            }

            if(this->command_exe != nullptr) this->command_exe->Release();

            delete this; // bye bye...

        };

        VE_COMMAND_PABA* command_exe; // <- REFERENCE TO BASE CLASS

        void execute(){

            switch(this->type){

                case VE_FCT_FUNC:
                    this->func_exe();
                    break;

                case VE_FCT_FUNC_PARAM:
                    this->func_param_exe((*(this->pParam1)));
                    break;

                case VE_FCT_FUNC_TWO_PARAM:
                    this->func_two_param_exe((*(this->pParam1)), (*(this->pParam2)));
                    break;

                default:
                    DebugBreak();
                    break;

            };

            if(this->command_exe != nullptr){

                this->command_exe->execute();

            }

        };

};

template <typename ParentClassType, typename ReturnValueType, typename Param1Type, typename Param2Type> class VE_DERIVED_FUNC_COMMAND : public VE_COMMAND_PABA {

    public:

        enum VE_DERIVED_FUNC_COMMAND_TYPE {

            VE_DFCT_FUNC,
            VE_DFCT_FUNC_PARAM,
            VE_DFCT_FUNC_TWO_PARAM,

        } type;

        Param1Type* pParam1;
        Param2Type* pParam2;

        Param1Type** lpParam1;
        Param2Type** lpParam2;

        bool params_allocated;

        ParentClassType* pParent;
        ParentClassType** lpParent;
        ReturnValueType (ParentClassType::*child_func_exe) ();
        ReturnValueType (ParentClassType::*child_param_exe) (Param1Type parameter);
        ReturnValueType (ParentClassType::*child_func_two_param_exe) (Param1Type parameter1, Param2Type parameter2);

        void Release(){

            if(params_allocated){

                if(pParam1 != nullptr) free(pParam1);
                if(pParam2 != nullptr) free(pParam2);

            }

            if(this->command_exe != nullptr) this->command_exe->Release();

            delete this; // bye bye ...

        };

        VE_COMMAND_PABA* command_exe; // <- REFERENCE TO BASE CLASS

        void execute(){

            switch(this->type){

                case VE_DFCT_FUNC:
                    if(this->pParent != nullptr){

                        (this->pParent->*this->child_func_exe)();

                    }else{

                        ((*(this->lpParent))->*this->child_func_exe)();

                    }
                    break;

                case VE_DFCT_FUNC_PARAM:
                    if(this->pParent != nullptr){

                        (this->pParent->*this->child_param_exe)((*(this->pParam1)));

                    }else{

                        ((*(this->lpParent))->*this->child_param_exe)((*(this->pParam1)));

                    }
                    break;

                case VE_DFCT_FUNC_TWO_PARAM:
                    if(this->pParent != nullptr){

                        (this->pParent->*this->child_func_two_param_exe)((*(this->pParam1)), (*(this->pParam2)));

                    }else{

                        ((*(this->lpParent))->*this->child_func_two_param_exe)((*(this->pParam1)), (*(this->pParam2)));

                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    DebugBreak();
                    break;

            };

            if(this->command_exe != nullptr){

                this->command_exe->execute();

            }

        };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be complicated but I think you're trying to achieve/experiment following :

```
template <typename Type> 
using Func = void (myClass<Type>::*)();


template <typename Type> 
void fGiveMeYourClass(Func<Type> fptr )
{

}
```

If I understood correctly, the *simplest and plain* way to get your pointer to member function working would be :

```
template <typename Type> 
void fGiveMeYourClass(const myClass<Type>& x)
{ 
   (x.*x.func_exe)(); 
}
```

Comment: well basically yes, but I forgot to mention that I don't want the need to template `fGiveMeYourClass` (since it makes the resulting code look unclean and forces me to template everything using that class when all I want is a pointer to one of its member functions)